# Applying and requirements for a Phd program

Tags: phd, masters

I am currently holding a diploma in computer science which is equivallent to a BSc. I have also finished my MAS (master of advanced studies) in economy, which was made up out of 5 CAS modules.

Now I would love to attend a doctoral program and research in the field of predictive modelling, machine learning and computational vision.

However my MAS diploma seems not to be enough to apply for a Phd program (except for DBA programs which only exists in the field of economy). Many (all?) programs require a MSc.

**Questions**

- Is the only way to get there attending to another master program to get my MSc?
- Are there Phd programs I can apply to that only require a MAS that I just havent found yet?
- Is there some equivalent to a DBA but in the field of computational science?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Consider programs outside your country, which may have different requirements.  For instance in the US, it is still very normal to NOT have a masters prior to starting the Ph.D. (only have a bachelors).

P.s.  Very hard to help you with a country-specific issue if you won't tell us the country!